# how to keep string as it original format in ajax?

Tags: json, ajax

I am sending some value by ajax request as follows:

```
    $('#compileBtn').on('click', function(evnt){
            evnt.preventDefault();
            var souceCode = cEditor.getValue();
            console.log(souceCode);
      var button = $(this),
          ajax_url = '<?php echo admin_url("admin-ajax.php"); ?>',
          data = {
              action: 'get_output_by_ajax',
              sourceCode : souceCode,
              lang: 2,
              testcases: ["1"],
              security: '<?php echo wp_create_nonce("get_output"); ?>'
          };

      $.post(ajax_url, data, function (response) {
                // obj = JSON.parse(response);
                 console.log(response);
      }).always(function () {
          $('.result-processing').addClass('hide');
      });

    });
```

I just return the value I received as follows:
function get_states_by_ajax_callback(){

```
  check_ajax_referer('get_output','security');
  $sourceCode = $_POST['sourceCode'];

   echo $sourceCode; wp_die();
}
```

Have a look, I used two console.log() to print the value before ajax request and after getting the ajax request by `console.log(souceCode);` and  `console.log(response);` respectively. But `souceCode` has been changed as follows:
**before ajax request send:**

```
 #include<iostream>
     using namespace std;
     int main()
     {
     cout<<"Hello Wold!"<<endl<<"How are you?";
      return 0;
      }
```

**After receiving ajax request**

```
#include<iostream>
 using namespace std;
 int main()
 {
 cout<<\"Hello Wold!\"<<endl<<\"How are you?\";
  return 0;
  }
```

That means backslash added before ". How can I keep same or convert it to its original form?

Comment: Where is the JSON you mentioned in the question title? I don't see `JSON.stringify` in the JavaScript and I don't see `json_encode` in the PHP.

Comment: Are you using a hidiously out of date and unsupported version of php with [Magic Quotes](http://php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.php) turned on?

Comment: Are you sure there are ```\``` characters in the data and they aren't just part of the *This is a string* **visualisation** of your `console.log` call?

Comment: You are comparing the raw format with the response in a json encoded way, of course it's different

Comment: Sorry for wrong title @Quentin  
I am using  php version: 7.0.29. Is there any idea to keep my data as same it was? Thanks for your time.